# Incorrect UTC value for epoch timestamp

Tags: date, datetime, epoch, milliseconds

I am storing birthday as epoch timestamp. For everything else it works fine but for a person whose birthday is on 1968-08-06, epoch timestamp comes as  -44323200000. When I try to convert this epoch timestamp back to date, it gives me erroneous result (screenshot attached). Surprisingly for someone whose birthday is on 1961-02-27 (epoch timestamp -279072000000), it works perfectly.[image: source : epochconverter.com]

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Epoch & Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools](https://www.epochconverter.com). This site tries to guess whether the number you enter is in seconds or milliseconds since the epoch and sometimes guesses incorrectly.

If I enter -44323200 (seconds), I correctly get “**GMT**: Tuesday, August 6, 1968 12:00:00 AM”. If I enter -44323200000 and intend it to be milliseconds, the site still conceives it as seconds and gives me “**GMT**: Saturday, June 15, 0565 12:00:00 AM”, 1453 years ago.

I have not found a way to indicate whether the number entered is seconds or milliseconds. There are other online epoch time converters out there. [current millis](https://currentmillis.com), for example, always assumes milliseconds. When I enter -44323200000, I get Tue Aug 06 1968 00:00:00.

That said, using a millisecond value to record a birthday seems to me to be overly precise. If that were me, I’d consider the date in an ISO 8601 format string, like `1968-08-06`. Or if it needs to be a number, then *days* since the epoch rather than milliseconds. For example -513 for 1968-08-06. [Convert days and seconds since 1970 etc.](http://www.toly.net/dayssince1970.html) can translate.